# Failed to serialize user into session, passport.js local strategy in express

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, passport.js

Checking a user base from mysql when logging in, I am getting the following error from passport.js:

Error: Failed to serialize user into session
at pass (/NodeJS/Projects/user-management/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:296:19)
at serialized (/NodeJS/Projects/user-management/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:301:7)
at /NodeJS/Projects/user-management/src/services/passport-config.js:27:44
at pass (/NodeJS/Projects/user-management/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:309:9)
at Authenticator.serializeUser (/NodeJS/Projects/user-management/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:314:5)
at /NodeJS/Projects/user-management/node_modules/passport/lib/sessionmanager.js:33:10
at Immediate._onImmediate (/NodeJS/Projects/user-management/node_modules/express-session/session/store.js:54:5)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21)

I worked from a tutorial that used syncronous user data (just push to array) and adapted the code for use with user data from MYSQL.

If I write code myself from scratch I usually work with async functions and await - so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong with .then on the webUsers constant. Without .then I am getting a type error (is not a function), so the promise seems to be resolving fine.

As you might pick up, I am in my first year of coding and with brand new subjects, mistages are not overly obvious to me yet.

What am I doing wrong here?

My passport.js configuration:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


function initPassport(passport, getUserByName, getUserById) {
    const authenticateUser = async (name, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByName(name)
        if (user == null) {
            return done(null, false, { message : 'No user with that name'})
        }

        try {
            if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect'})
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return done(e)
        }
    }
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'name'},
    authenticateUser))
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => { 
        return done(null, getUserById(id))
     })
}

module.exports = initPassport //used in routes web-user-routes , TODO: move functions to own controller and services
```

My app (getting it to work as a whole in the route before breaking it up into controller and services):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passport = require('passport');
const flash = require('express-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
let { singledbentry, refresh, refreshTwo } = require("../services/db.js")
const controller = require('../controllers/web-user-controller');

const webUsers = refresh('SELECT useruniqueid, username, password, userrole, email FROM webusers')
webUsers.then((users) => {
    const initPassport = require('../services/passport-config.js');
    initPassport(
        passport, 
        name => users.find(user => user.username === name),
        id => users.find(user => user.useruniqueid === id)
    )
})

router.use(flash())
router.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
router.use(passport.initialize())
router.use(passport.session())
router.use(methodOverride('_method'))


router.get('/webusers', async (_req, res, next) => {
    let userData = refresh('SELECT useruniqueid, username, password, userrole, email FROM webusers')
    res.render('webusers', { data: await userData });
})

router.post('/webusers', async (req, res) => {
    let userUniqueId = Date.now().toString()
    let userName = req.body.username
    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    let userRole = req.body.userrole
    let userEmail = req.body.email
    
let sql = "insert into webusers values(?,?,?,?,?)";
let sqlValues = [userUniqueId, userName, hashedPassword, userRole, userEmail];
await refreshTwo(sql, sqlValues);

let userData = refresh('SELECT useruniqueid, username, password, userrole, email FROM webusers')
res.render('webusers', { data: await userData });
})

router.post('/webusers/delete', async (req, res) => {
let deleteId = req.body.useruniqueid;
let sql = "delete from webusers where useruniqueid ='" + deleteId + "';"
await singledbentry(sql);

let userData = refresh('SELECT useruniqueid, username, password, userrole, email FROM webusers')
res.render('webusers', { data: await userData });
})

router.get('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs');
})

router.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))

router.get('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render('register.ejs');
})

router.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let userUniqueId = Date.now().toString()
        let userName = req.body.name
        let userRole = 'USER'
        let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        let userEmail = req.body.email
        
    let sql = "insert into webusers values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    let sqlValues = [userUniqueId, userName, hashedPassword, userRole, userEmail];
    await refreshTwo(sql, sqlValues);
        res.redirect('/login')
    } catch {
        res.redirect('/register')
    }
})

router.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/login')
})

// Delete uses library method override and uses the following code frontend:
// <form action="/logout?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
// <button type="submit">Log Out</button></form>

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}

function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user.role === 'ADMIN') {
        return next();
    }
    console.log('nope!')
    return res.redirect('/');
}

module.exports = router;
```

My MYSQL Table setup:

```
// CREATE TABLES FOR <<<<< WEB-USERS >>>>> IF NOT EXIST
async function initWebUserTable() {
    await pool.query ('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS webusers (useruniqueid VARCHAR(45), username VARCHAR(45), password VARCHAR(99), userrole VARCHAR(45), email VARCHAR(45), PRIMARY KEY (useruniqueid))');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

I had not been consistent with the names of the keys, overlooking that the object from database will use two object keys differently = columname.

So I ended up with passport working with "username" and "uniqueuserid" instead of "name" and "id"

Many thanks nevertheless!